# Test target encountered an error (iOS Simulator failed to install the application.)

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration

I'm using Xcode continuous integration and I get these 2 errors when running the tests. It doesn't install on the Simulators but when I have actual devices connected, it installs on the physical devices. I've tried resetting all the simulators and it still doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Test target encountered an error (iOS Simulator failed to install the application.)
Test target encountered an error (Simulator in use. The Simulator can't be launched because it is already in use.)